# How to heal a scabby bald area on cats back

Tags: cats, behavior, health

Since my cat had his tail amputated he's been nibbling at his back and making bald, scabby patches of skin. How can I get this to heal?

Answer (score 1):

I would take him to the vet. I don't know anything of your cat's medical history and this might be another problem. The vet or you should check him for fleas and ticks (preferably the vet) and if that is not the case, the vet will probably recommend something like this.

http://vetericyn.com/vetericyn-pet-care/

If you like, you could even try this before a visit to the vet. If the problem persists make sure you take him to the vet.

Answer (score 1):

I second that - the vet needs to see him to determine what is going on.

Heaven forbid it but he might have to wear an Elizabethan collar (also known a "cones" for a few days to prevent him getting at the area.

I say "Heaven forbid" because cats simply are not happy, don't eat as well - or do anything well when wearing a collar.

We don't even put collars on them after they are neutered or spayed and we have not had a single problem - in the 30 years of our marriage, my wife and I have had about 23 cats neutered or spayed and none of them wore collars.

But in the case of your cat, you need a vet to figure out the reason he is biting at the area.

If he keeps it up, an infection could occur in the area and that would not be good, no infection is good.